# zfs regular read pauses

Tags: zfs, openindiana

We have a zfs file system running on openindiana with an almost purely read-only workload. Recently we have found that the io is blocked or pauses every 1 minute for around 2-3 seconds. Does anyone know why this happens and how to stop it occurring?

```
pool: data

state: ONLINE

status: The pool is formatted using a legacy on-disk format.  The pool can
        still be used, but some features are unavailable.

action: Upgrade the pool using 'zpool upgrade'.  Once this is done, the
        pool will no longer be accessible on software that does not support feature
        flags.

scan: none requested

config:

        NAME                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        data01                     ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0                 ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97A6BAB722Fd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97BBE7FE8F1d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97CB2D1609Fd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97E0D2BC6ACd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97E1E2A6F66d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97E4C627FC0d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97E44EB7FC0d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97E124F8168d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97E86762E4Dd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97E25716311d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97EBEEB8B60d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c6t5E83A97FCF5551F5d0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

As requested by @jlliagre, here are the results from calling hotkernel during good and bad times.

**good times**

- zfs`vdev_is_dead                                            1   0.0%
- ip`conn_ip_output                                           1   0.0%
- sd`sdintr                                                   1   0.0%
- mpt_sas`mptsas_start_cmd0                                   1   0.0%
- genunix`new_mstate                                          1   0.0%
- genunix`segvn_faulta                                        1   0.0%
- unix`swtch                                                  1   0.0%
- unix`tsc_scalehrtime                                        1   0.0%
- zfs`ddt_stat_add                                            1   0.0%
- unix`lwp_segregs_save                                       1   0.0%
- rootnex`rootnex_get_sgl                                     1   0.0%
- genunix`ldi_strategy                                        1   0.0%
- mpt_sas`mptsas_scsi_init_pkt                                1   0.0%
- genunix`ddi_fm_dma_err_get                                  1   0.0%
- zfs`zio_create                                              1   0.0%
- zfs`zio_destroy                                             1   0.0%
- unix`strcmp                                                 1   0.0%
- unix`cpu_acpi_idle                                          1   0.0%
- ip`ip_xmit_attach_llhdr                                     1   0.0%
- genunix`mdi_pi_get_vhci_private                             1   0.0%
- genunix`lbolt_event_driven                                  1   0.0%
- unix`disp                                                   1   0.0%
- genunix`cpu_update_pct                                      1   0.0%
- unix`tsc_gethrtime                                          1   0.0%
- ip`tcp_build_hdrs                                           1   0.0%
- genunix`dnlc_lookup                                         1   0.0%
- unix`page_create_va                                         1   0.0%
- genunix`kmem_zalloc                                         1   0.0%
- unix`mmapobj_map_elf                                        1   0.0%
- bnx`bnx_intr_1lvl                                           1   0.0%
- genunix`btopr                                               1   0.0%
- genunix`fsflush                                             1   0.0%
- genunix`gexec                                               1   0.0%
- unix`mmu_tlbflush_entry                                     1   0.0%
- unix`hment_alloc                                            1   0.0%
- specfs`spec_lockcsp                                         1   0.0%
- zfs`vdev_stat_update                                        1   0.0%
- genunix`stk_getptr                                          1   0.0%
- unix`resume                                                 1   0.0%
- unix`do_splx                                                1   0.0%
- unix`page_clr_all_props                                     1   0.0%
- bnx`bnx_xmit_ring_xmit_mblk                                 1   0.0%
- genunix`list_create                                         1   0.0%
- scsi`scsi_uscsi_handle_cmd                                  1   0.0%
- unix`page_lookup_nowait                                     1   0.0%
- genunix`syscall_mstate                                      1   0.0%
- genunix`kmem_free                                           1   0.0%
- genunix`as_map_locked                                       1   0.0%
- unix`cpu_idle_adaptive                                      1   0.0%
- unix`page_lookup_create                                     1   0.0%
- sd`sd_start_cmds                                            1   0.0%
- unix`0xfffffffffb85                                         1   0.0%
- unix`atomic_cas_64                                          1   0.0%
- genunix`restorectx                                          1   0.0%
- genunix`vmem_is_populator                                   1   0.0%
- unix`disp_anywork                                           1   0.0%
- unix`prefetch_page_r                                        1   0.0%
- sd`xbuf_iostart                                             1   0.0%
- zfs`zfs_read                                                1   0.0%
- unix`hwblkclr                                               1   0.0%
- specfs`sfind                                                1   0.0%
- genunix`swapfs_getvp                                        1   0.0%
- zfs`vdev_cache_allocate                                     1   0.0%
- zfs`buf_hash_find                                           1   0.0%
- genunix`taskq_thread                                        2   0.0%
- unix`tsc_read                                               2   0.0%
- unix`tsc_gethrtimeunscaled                                  2   0.0%
- genunix`fop_getpage                                         2   0.0%
- unix`inflate_table                                          2   0.0%
- unix`ddi_get32                                              2   0.0%
- unix`mutex_exit                                             2   0.0%
- unix`idle                                                   3   0.0%
- zfs`lzjb_compress                                           3   0.0%
- unix`mutex_enter                                            6   0.1%
- unix`page_nextn                                             9   0.1%
- genunix`fsflush_do_pages                                    9   0.1%
- unix`disp_getwork                                          12   0.2%
- unix`acpi_cpu_cstate                                      441   5.7%
- unix`i86_mwait                                           7118  92.7%

**bad times**

- genunix`cpu_update_pct                                      1   0.0%
- unix`splr                                                   1   0.0%
- bnx`bnx_timer                                               1   0.0%
- unix`av_check_softint_pending                               1   0.0%
- genunix`devid_str_decode_id                                 1   0.0%
- pcplusmp`apic_send_ipi                                      1   0.0%
- genunix`callout_downheap                                    1   0.0%
- unix`prefetch_page_r                                        1   0.0%
- dtrace`dtrace_state_clean                                   1   0.0%
- genunix`fsflush                                             1   0.0%
- unix`link_ptp                                               1   0.0%
- ip`ip_input_cksum_v4                                        1   0.0%
- ip`tcp_timer_callback                                       1   0.0%
- unix`page_pptonum                                           1   0.0%
- unix`do_splx                                                1   0.0%
- unix`page_nextn                                             5   0.1%
- genunix`fsflush_do_pages                                    6   0.1%
- unix`acpi_cpu_cstate                                      782  17.7%
- unix`i86_mwait

Comment: More details about the hardware and pool layout, please...

Comment: The zpool contains 12 ssd's in raidz-1 configuration. The load is made up of a large number of small random reads.

Comment: And how much RAM do you have? Is there any L2ARC? Can you provide the output of `zpool status -v`?

Comment: The server has 64 gb ram. The cache hit ratio is fairly poor so we have decided not to use an L2ARC.

Comment: You might want to use dtrace to identify what the OS is doing during the pauses. I would suggest starting with the hotkernel script.

Comment: hotkernel script is not showing anything obvious (to me)

Comment: @PhilHoy Have you looked at disk-busy figures?

Comment: @PhilHoy Please use the @ + name prefix when replying for notifications to occur. You should run hotkernel twice, the first one during a normal period, the second one when the problem occurs then post the results.

Comment: Have you run a scrub on your system since this problem started?

Comment: Status of C-states? And to pre-empt an answer of 'on', turn off C-states. They are a huge killer of performance (for instance, you'll never get full 10Gbe if C-states is on, fun huh?). You can't really (AFAIK) disable them fully in OS. Go into your BIOS, find anything about C-States and disable it. Then find where it talks about power, and set it to 'Performance' or the equivalent. If your CPU is capable of dropping below C1 (or maybe C1E), you're going to feel performance penalties, and at times you wouldn't even expect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps is there an issue with power management on your machine.

Try disabling it by adding the following line to the `/etc/power.conf` file

```
cpupm disable
```

next run

```
pmconfig
```

and see if the I/O behavior changes.

---

**Update**:

As disabling power management doesn't change anything, the fact is the kernel is essentially idle during the "Bad times" with zero ZFS activity,.

I would then infer the application is not I/O bound and is simply doing something else during these periods of time.

Comment: Tried that and it did not help. Nice ideas though.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back ! Don't forget to revert power management back to default by removing the cpupm line and running pmconfig again.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: I had already ruled out the application as a possible cause of the pauses however @jlliagre's wise words forced my to take another look. Embarrassingly i was barking up the wrong tree and the app was to blame. Thanks everyone one and sorry to take up your time.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a few things wrong here...

- Your zpool version is old. `zpool upgrade` will fix that.
- The pool design does not lend itself to high performance. You have the effective IOPS potential of *one* disk. (this is likely the biggest issue here)
- You have too many drives in your RAIDZ1. You shouldn't go over 7...
- There are likely other tunables that may help here. Can you show `zfs list`?

Take a read of: http://nex7.blogspot.com/2013/03/readme1st.html for more general guidelines.

Comment: I would like to stress the performance WAS very good until recently when it started pausing every minute. Inbetween the pauses the performance is great.

zfs list

NAME                          USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT

data01                       2.98T  1.71T  42.0K  /data01